# ERROR - 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply' or str has no attribute str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe column in numeric format with decimal point. What I need for this column is

1. Remove that .0 at the end
2. Left pad it with zeros until the length is 12. (If it is less than 12).
3. Truncate the column to 12 characters if it has more than 12.

I've tried the below solution, but I'm struggling to find out why the subsequent error is thrown:

```
df_out['MY_COLUMN'] = df_out['MY_COLUMN'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True).\
        str.zfill(12).apply(lambda x: x.str[:12])

ERROR - 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

I've also tried removing the .str as I would assume the conversion to str is done in the astype(str) but got this error:

```
ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: `...regex=True).zfill(12).apply(lambda x: x[:12])`

Comment: What is dataframe? pandas?

Comment: @PeterWood yeah, sorry, it's pandas dataframe.

Comment: @PeterWood it now says 'Series' object has no attribute 'zfill' with your proposed solution ...regex=True).zfill(12).apply(lambda x: x[:12])